# Redis: Does replication without Multi-AZ makes sense?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

On creating a Redis cluster you can enable replication and alternatively the Multi-AZ feature. My question is: Is there any benefit to **not enable** it? If you are using replication I suppose that you always want the automatic failover of the Multi-AZ as it is explained [here in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoFailover.html). After some searching I even found that's also free of charge. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to not enable Multi-AZ for your redis cache. When creating the cache cluster from aws console, it comes as selected by default.

When one of the aws zone goes down, this will allow your cluster to select a primary from the instances available in the other region.

Of-course the aws documentation is exhaustive, but I found this blog which explains it in simpler words.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elasticache-redis-multi-az/

Answer (score 0):

I would read the section titled "Notes on Multi-AZ with Automatic Failover" here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoFailover.html just to make sure those items listed aren't deal-breakers for you. Otherwise, I think you would always want multi-az unless replication speed is more important to you than disaster recovery.